# Array Function of MPMediaItem Very Slow

Tags: swift, media-player, mpmediaitem, apple-musickit, data-race

I'm trying to edit the queue of my music player using the `applicationQueuePlayer` and the `perform` method (details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayerapplicationcontroller/2815055-perform)). However, whenever I apply any array function (`map`, `filter` etc.), it takes many seconds to complete, leading to (I think) data races and crashes when the user, for example, removes two tracks immediately after each other.

```
    var musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer

    self.musicPlayerController.perform { (currentQueue) in
        let items = currentQueue.items
        let itemsToRemove = items.filter { $0.artist == "Some artist" } // this takes multiple seconds
        if let item = itemsToRemove.first {
            currentQueue.remove(item)
        }
    } completionHandler: { (newQueue, error) in
        if let e = error {
            print(e)
        } else {
            tracks = items.map { Track(item: $0) } // this takes multiple seconds
        }
    }
```

The issue is arising as I'm going through an `MPMediaItem` array. I don't think this is an issue with the MPMediaItem class though, as I'm able to complete a `map` of [MPMediaItem] in other places in the app e.g. when getting items from a playlist (a similar sized array to the queue items).

The issue happens solely when the `MPMediaItems` are taken from the `MPMusicPlayerControllerMutableQueue` and `MPMusicPlayerControllerQueue`

Is this just a bug with MusicKit API?

Comment: I've not the answer but filtering the whole items to remove the first one is not optimize. Instead: `if let item = items.first(where: { $0.artist = "Some artist" } { currentQueue.remove(item) }`. What crash do you have? Which one is causing it? `tracks`?

Comment: Yeah it’s a simplified bit of code - but I’ve left a bit in, so should remove the if let check and go straight to the remove method. I’m getting an Exc_bad_access crash

Comment: Both the filter and the map methods cause the crash – and any other array function that takes ages to cycle through

Comment: This seems really strange to me. How big is `items`? If it's huge, does something like `let items = currentQueue.items.prefix(100)` help? Clearly that's not what you want to do in production, but it could help us diagnose. You could also try doing `let items = currentQueue.items.lazy`. This will probably cause compiler errors due to mis-matched types, but avoid wrapping things in `Array` and instead actually store a `LazySequence<IndexingIterator<Array<Element>>>` (probably can spell this just `LazySequence`) and you _might_ see better performance.

Comment: Also make sure you're using the [`enumerateValues(forProperties:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaentity/1620122-enumeratevalues) in your `Track` initializer if you are using multiple media properties.

Comment: Thanks Deaton for your suggestions, and while the issue is more pronounced on bigger arrays, iteration is definitely slower item for item when it comes from the queue. I've written a small app to demonstrate the issue, which can be seen here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682064?login=true&page=1